# Proof of Euler's reflection formula via rapidly decreasing Fourier series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, riemann-zeta-function, gamma-function

### Story

I want to prove [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) by showing that

\begin{equation*}
 f(s) = \sin(\pi s) \Gamma(s) \Gamma(1 - s)
\end{equation*}

is constant, where $s = \sigma + it$. It's easy to see that $f$ is entire and $f(s + 1) = f(s)$, so for fixed $t$ we have $f \in C(\mathbb{R})^\infty$ and $f(\sigma + it)$ is 1-periodic. Therefore $f$ has a rapidly decreasing Fourier series for fixed $s$

\begin{equation*}
f(s) = \sum _{n \in \mathbb{Z}} c_n(t) e^{i 2 \pi n \sigma}.
\end{equation*}

Let's have a look at the $m$-th term. By definition we have
\begin{equation*}
 f_m(s) = \left(\int _0 ^1 f(s + x) e^{- i 2 \pi m x} dx\right) e^{i 2 \pi m \sigma} = c_m(t) e^{i 2 \pi m \sigma}.
\end{equation*}

### Problem

Now to my problem and question: **Is $f_m$ analytic and why**? I can't find an argument and I need one to justify the use of the Cauchy-Riemann equations later on.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a version of Leibniz's rule (for differentiation under the integral sign) for complex-analytic functions.  This is standard, and should be in just about any textbook in complex analysis.  By the way, you can use Stirling's bound on the gamma function to show that $|f(s)|$ is bounded in any fixed strip.

Comment: Of course, $f$ is analytic (it is constant!). The answer really depends on what you want to use about $\sin$ and $\Gamma$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I was asking about the analyticity of $f_m$ and I still have to show that $f$ is constant. That's what the proof is all about.

Comment: @fje: My question was what properties of $\sin$ and $\Gamma$ are you willing to use for your proof. Do you want to use that $1/\Gamma$ is entire with simple poles at negative integers?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko You mean $\frac{1}{\Gamma}$ is entire with zeros right at the simple poles of $\Gamma$? I unfortunately can't use this fact as I'm going to deduce it from Euler's reflection formula.

Comment: if you meant $f_m(s) = e^{2 i \pi m s}\int_0^1 f(s+x) e^{- 2 i \pi m x}  dx$ then yes it is holomorphic (hence also analytic) since $f(s)$ doesn't have any pole (it is entire) hence no problem for switching $\frac{d}{ds}$ and $\int$ hence $f_m'(s)$ is well-defined for every $s \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @fje: Then state explicitly which facts are you willing to use. Otherwise your question makes no sense.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : it is obvious that he starts from $\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-x} dx, \Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s)$. that $f(s)$ is entire is easy to prove, but that $\Gamma(s)$ has no zero is much less.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but shouldn't the $s$ under integral sign just be an $it$? Then you have a product of a function depending only on $t$ (the integral), and one depending only on $\sigma$ (the other factor).

Comment: @SebastianGoette I think $s$ should be correct. You would have $f(it + x)$ if you changed the integral bounds to $\sigma$ and $\sigma + 1$

Comment: The actual argument $\sigma$ should not appear in the formula for the Fourier coefficient, see the answer below.

Comment: @fje : I tried to conclude this way (from the analytic continuation of a Fourier series) on the boundedness of $f(s)$ but I didn't find. did you ? what we have to prove is that $f(s) = \sum_m c_m e^{2 i \pi m s}$ where $c_m = o(e^{-a m})$ for every $a$, but how would you get that ? (I can only show that $c_m = o(m^{-a})$ for every $a$ from the $C^\infty$-ness of $f(\sigma)$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\sigma\mapsto f(\sigma+it)$ is periodic with period $1$, for any value
of $t$. Therefore
$$f(\sigma+it)=\sum_{n\in Z} c_n(t)e^{2\pi i n\sigma}.$$
It follows that 
$$c_n(t)=\int_0^1 f(x+it) e^{-2\pi i n x}\,dx.$$
The $n$-th term in the Fourier expansion is, with $s=\sigma+it$
\begin{multline*}
f_m(s)=f_m(\sigma+it)=c_n(t)e^{2\pi i n\sigma}=e^{2\pi i n\sigma}
\int_0^1f(x+it) e^{-2\pi i n x}\,dx\\
=\int_0^1 f(x+it) e^{-2\pi i n (x-\sigma)}\,dx
= \int_{-\sigma}^{1-\sigma} f(x+\sigma+it) e^{-2\pi i n x}\,dx
\end{multline*}

By the periodicity the limits of the integral can be changed to $0$ and $1$, 
therefore
$$f_m(s)=\int_0^1f(s+x)e^{-2\pi i n x}\,dx.$$
That is not what you write in your question.  In this form the analyticity 
of $f_m$ is easy. For example consider Theorem 5.4 in the book

E. M. Stein and R. Shakarchi, Complex Analysis, Princeton University Press, 
2003.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't realise that my $f_m$ was just wrong.